# Operator overloading error

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have code here that I am trying to understand operator overloading, I have hit a road block with an error I don't understand fully. The error has 3 LNK2019 errors on it, reading unresolved external symbol. I want to know what the error is and how I can fix it. Thanks for your help in advance.

This is my implementation code.

```
ComplexNumber::ComplexNumber()
{
double complexNumberValue = 0.00;
double realNumberValue = 0.00;
}

ComplexNumber::ComplexNumber(double real, double imaginary)
{
realNumberValue = real;
complexNumberValue = imaginary;
}

ComplexNumber ComplexNumber::operator*(const ComplexNumber& rho) const
{
double newValue = realNumberValue * rho.getValue();
ComplexNumber newNumber(newValue, complexNumberValue);
return newNumber;

}

ComplexNumber ComplexNumber::operator+(const ComplexNumber& rho) const
{
double newValue = realNumberValue + rho.getValue();
ComplexNumber newNumber(newValue, complexNumberValue);
return newNumber;
}

ComplexNumber ComplexNumber::operator-(const ComplexNumber& rho) const
{
double newValue = realNumberValue - rho.getValue();
ComplexNumber newNumber(newValue, complexNumberValue);
return newNumber;
}

ComplexNumber ComplexNumber::operator/(const ComplexNumber& rho) const
{
double newValue = realNumberValue / rho.getValue();
ComplexNumber newNumber(newValue, complexNumberValue);
return newNumber;
}

ComplexNumber ComplexNumber::operator=(const ComplexNumber& rho)
{
realNumberValue = rho.realNumberValue;
return *this;
}

bool operator==(const ComplexNumber& leftOp, const ComplexNumber& rightOp)
{
    if (leftOp.getValue() == rightOp.getValue())
    {
    return true;
    }
    else
    {
    return false;
    }
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const ComplexNumber& rho)
{
out << rho.getValue();
return out;
}
```

This is my driver code.

```
#include "ComplexNumbers.h"

int main()
{
// Create complex numbers to do arithmentic with
ComplexNumber cm1(1, 2);
ComplexNumber cm2(1, -2);

// test addition operator
ComplexNumber cm3 = cm1 + cm2;
cout << cm3 << endl;

// test subtraction operator
ComplexNumber cm4 = cm1 - cm2;
cout << cm4 << endl;

// test multiplication operator
ComplexNumber cm5 = cm1 * cm2;
cout << cm5 << endl;

// test division operator
ComplexNumber cm6 = cm1 / cm2;
cout << cm6 << endl;

// test assignment operator
cm6 = cm5;
cout << cm6 << endl;

// test comparison operator
if (cm1 == cm2)
    cout << "\nThey are equal.\n";
else
    cout << "\nThey are not equal.";

ComplexNumber cm8(1, 2);
if (cm1 == cm8)
    cout << "\nThey are equal.\n";
else
    cout << "\nThey are not equal.";

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Here is the header file that is requested

```
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

class ComplexNumber
{
public:
//Constructor
//Purpose: Set the value of ComplexNumber to 0
//Parameters: None
//Returns: None
ComplexNumber();

//Parameterized Constructor
//Purpose: Set the value of ComplexNumber to the parameter
//Parameters: A double, and a double
//Returns: None
ComplexNumber(double, double);

//getValue
//Purpose:Getter for complexNumberValue
//Parameters: None
//Returns: the double value of object
double getValue() const;

//plusOverload
//Purpose: Overload the + operator 
//Parameters: The ComplexNumber on the right side of the operator
//Returns: A new ComplexNumber object containing the sum
ComplexNumber operator+(const ComplexNumber&) const;

//minusOverload
//Purpose: Overload the - operator 
//Parameters: The ComplexNumber on the right side of the operator
//Returns: A new ComplexNumber object containing the difference
ComplexNumber operator-(const ComplexNumber&) const;

//multiplicationOverload
//Purpose: Overload the * operator 
//Parameters: The ComplexNumber on the right side of the operator
//Returns: A new ComplexNumber object containing the product
ComplexNumber operator*(const ComplexNumber&) const;

//divisionOverload
//Purpose: Overload the / operator 
//Parameters: The ComplexNumber on the right side of the operator
//Returns: A new ComplexNumber object containing the quotient
ComplexNumber operator/(const ComplexNumber&) const;

//assignment
//Purpose: Overload the = operator
//Parameters: The two ComplexNumbers we want to assign
//Returns: 
ComplexNumber operator=(const ComplexNumber&);

//comparison
//Purpose: Overload the == operator 
//Parameters: The two ComplexNumbers we want to compare
//Returns: 
bool operator==(const ComplexNumber&) const;

private:
double complexNumberValue;
double realNumberValue;
};

//Independant Functions

//streamInsertionOverload
//Purpose: Overload the stream insertion operator
//Parameters: The stream object to read from, and object to read to
//Returns:The stream
ostream& operator<<(const ostream&, const ComplexNumber&);
```

And here are my errors

Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall ComplexNumber::operator==(class ComplexNumber const &)const " (??8ComplexNumber@@QBE_NABV0@@Z) referenced in function _main

Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_ostream > & __cdecl operator<<(class std::basic_ostream > const &,class ComplexNumber const &)" (??6@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@ABV01@ABVComplexNumber@@@Z) referenced in function _main

Error   3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: double __thiscall ComplexNumber::getValue(void)const " (?getValue@ComplexNumber@@QBENXZ) referenced in function "class std::basic_ostream > & __cdecl operator<<(class std::basic_ostream > &,class ComplexNumber const &)" (??6@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV01@ABVComplexNumber@@@Z)

Error   4   error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals

Comment: And the unresolved symbol(s) would be?

Comment: Post the contents of ComplexNumbers.h, and the exact error you get.

Comment: And what does the header file look like? And you *do* build with the "implementation file"?

Comment: At the very lease `ComplexNumber::operator=` should return `ComplexNumber&`.

Comment: Here is the new post with the information requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have realized that in my header file, I have a conflict of definition and declaration.  By removing the const in the header file I was able to get the program to compile.  I also needed to implement the getValue() function.